# PHP AJAX Postback with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

me again, i'm really getting into php now i just need to know a few things first. First of all i'm trying to do a postback to a the server without reloading the client page.  Here's an example of what i want to do: I have to textboxe, now when the user enters a number into both textboxes and clicks the add button, the total value should be calculated and displayed in the third textbox without reloading the page, i've read a bit on ajax but i'm having trouble implementing it.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["add"]))
    {
        $val1 = $_POST["val1"];
        $val2 = $_POST["val2"];

        $result = $val1 + $val2;
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($("#btn").click)
            {
                var request = $.ajax({
                url: "postback.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    val1 : "what goes here?",
                    val2 : "what goes here?"

                }

                });
                request.done(function(msg) {
                    $("#log").html( msg );
                });
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="input" name="val1">
        <input type="input" name="val2">
        <input type="input" name="result" value="<?php echo $result ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="btn" name="add">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue here is just that you didn't echo anything in PHP.

Comment: I echoed the value directly into the textbox. Check the html.

Comment: Okay, so debugging time. `var_dump($result)` at the top.

Comment: Nothing happens when i click the submit button, could it be a problem with my jquery?

Comment: Lol, sorry man, Siamak took me straight through step by step and i was able to get it.

Comment: Anyway i won't be able to post anything again, i've been banned from asking questions. :(

Comment: Definitely think you chose the wrong answer for this @GoIDRoger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to separate your JS and PHP follow this:
 

 1. You should set your input type as button `<input type="button" id="btn" name="add">`
 2. You should also post `add` in your ajax call
 3. You should get the values from textboxs `$('#val1').val()`
 4. You should stop the code after echoing two values because if you don't, ajax returns the rest of html codes and page contents.
 5. And at last you should add the new value to the third input by **JavaScript**, not php because it's ajax and the page is not going to reload.

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["add"])){
    $val1 = $_POST["val1"];
    $val2 = $_POST["val2"];
    $result = $val1+$val2;
    echo $result;
    die();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var request = $.ajax({
            url: "postback.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                val1 : $('#val1').val(),
                val2 : $('#val2').val(),
                add : "ok"
            }

            });
            request.done(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                $("#result").val( msg );
            });
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="input" id="val1">
    <input type="input" id="val2">
    <input type="input" id="result" value="">
    <input type="button" id="btn" name="add">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried it still nothing happens when i click the button.

Comment: @GolDRoger Have you included the `jquery.js`. is the file place beside `postback.php` and is this file name is `postback.php`? If yes, then check out the console and tell me the error if there is.

Comment: Thank you soo much itz working now. (Missed the id on the textboxes)

Comment: I still have a problem though, once in a while i keep getting "requestfailed: parsererror"

Comment: @GolDRoger This is another story, [Follow this](https://www.google.com/search?q=requestfailed%3A+parsererror&oq=requestfailed%3A+parsererror&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i58j69i62.1100j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Okay i'll do that but one last thing first(i know i'm pesky), supposing i want to return an array from php through the ajax postback and into javascript, how do i go about that?

Comment: @GolDRoger No you are not :) if you want to pass an array from php to javascript the best option is using json (JavaScript Object Notation). this is not relative to this question so I give you two easy tutorial link to learn how. [**PHP and ajax easy with json and jquery**](http://www.lunawebs.com/blog/2011/02/24/php-and-ajax-easy-with-json-and-jquery/) and [**jQuery, JSON, PHP, Simple Example For Read Data From table Database**](http://blog.abdulmajeedpk.com/2011/04/jquery-json-php-simple-read-data-table-database/)

Comment: TL;DR: Use `echo(json_encode($var));` in your PHP, and `$.parseJSON(var)` in your jQuery. Simples.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix your JavaScript and your PHP logic. Separate them.

You need your jQuery POSTing to another file, and in *this* file, echo out the result of your PHP.

This result will then be placed in the `.done()` method (although I would use `.success()`, and you use jQuery / JavaScript to update the contents of your HTML).

By the end of this you should have **no PHP whatsoever** in your HTML / JS file.

---

### Your PHP Code in test.php

From this, we can see you need to post a val1 and a val2 through, so here is a really basic script.

```
if (isset($_POST))
{
    $val1 = isset($_POST["val1"]) ? $_POST["val1"] : 'No value 1 passed through';
    $val2 = isset($_POST["val2"]) ? $_POST["val2"] : 'No value 2 passed through';

    if (is_int($val1) && is_int($val2))
    {
        // They're integers, add them
        $result = $val1 + $val2;
    }
    else
    {   
        // They're strings, append them
        $result = $val1 . $val2;
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

That is all you need in your PHP.

### Your HTML / JS

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'val1' : $("#val1").val(),
                'val2' : $("#val2").val()
            },
            success: function(data, status) {
                $("#result").html(data)
            }
        });
    });
});

<div id="result">Result should appear here</div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="val1" name="val2" />
    <input type="text" id="val2" name="val2" />
    <input type="submit" id="add" name="add" />
</form>
```

And that's it. Pretty simple. Note, untested, so give it a try.

Comment: Just a note: the user whose edit to this post was rejected was CORRECT. There is a missing hash for the id. Way to go getting newbies into the community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of

```
$result = $val1 + $val2;
```

use

```
echo $result;
exit;
```

Comment: should use `echo $result; exit;` if it post on the same url, or ajax will response the whole page again.

Comment: True that might be then echo $result; the answer :)

Comment: I echoed the $result directly into the textbox in the html plus when i click the add button nothing happens at all.